# How should I process the output from this neural network?

Tags: neural-network, audio-recognition

I have a neural network that takes an np.array of a mel spectrogram of a 3 second audio clip from a song as input, and outputs vector of individual predictions that it is from 494 given (individual) artists.

At first, I was getting whole songs, splitting them into 3 second clips, inputting each clip into the nn, and averaging the outputs. But this proved to be wonky.

I got advice that I should only need one 3 second clip, but this person had not worked in audio before. If I should do that, which 3 seecond clip should I get? For many songs, the first or last 3 seconds is silence, or does not sound like the song at all. For artist classification, that can get wonky.

What do you all advise?

Comment: Using average as the aggregation is the standard approach here. In what way did it "prove to be wonky" ?

Comment: Note that doing classification over 494 classes is quite tricky for a model. What may be more relevant is to build a distance function, which takes two audio clips and outputs their artist-similarity. This is the kind of approach used for face recognition etc